# performance comparison of math libraries

Tags: ros, bullet, eigen, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if anyone has benchmarked the performance of the commonly used math libraries in the ROS community such as the KDL, Bullet & Eigen. In my work, I have to do hundreds of thousands of rotations & transformations at run time and right now I'm primarily using the KDL but I never looked into the performance of the individual libraries to determine if one is much faster or much slower than the others.

In a quick search on ros.org, I found a couple of pages, [MathLibraries](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/MathLibraries) & [RotationMethods](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/RotationMethods), that discuss the libraries but don't offer a performance comparison. If someone has any insight into this topic, I'll post it on the MathLibraries page.

Should I assume that all of these libraries have comparable performance? If no one responds, then I'll just do some simple benchmarking of my own and post the results.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11889/performance-comparison-of-math-libraries/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2011-11-10**:
Thanks Armin. Yea, those stats are interesting but are hard for me to apply to work like we do - mainly 3D transforms.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-10**:
The Eigen benchmarks are also interesting: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark but only cover large matrix and vector operations, and not the traditional 3D coordinate transforms. Bullet at least looks highly optimized for that task.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-10**:
I would be interested in seeing this comparison as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Coming up with a good, representative benchmark for comparing math libraries is quite a lot of work. The results would be interesting, but maybe no one has done it yet for those libraries.

If you come up with comparisons of your own, please post a link on ros-users. I am sure many people will be interested in your results.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1